# JSONArray or JSONObject of value to bundle and send to server in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

i'm new to android and probably this is silly question but please help. i am receiving output as

contact Name: RRRR
phone Number: XXXXXXXXX
contact Name: SSSS
phone Number: YYYYYYYYY
phone Number: aaaaaaaaa
phone Number: zzzzzzzzz
contact Name: TTTT
phone Number: XXXXXXXXX
phone Number: ccccccccc
.
.
.

//code

```
public void readContacts() { 
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
sb.append("......Contact Details....."); 
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
String phone = null;
String name = null;

if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
        name = cur .getString(cur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        if (Integer .parseInt(cur.getString(cur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) { 
            System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id); sb.append("\n Contact Name:" + name);
            Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                phone = pCur .getString(pCur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            sb.append("\n Phone number:" + phone+":"+pCur.getCount()); System.out.println("phone" + phone);
            }pCur.close();
        }
        outputText.setText(sb);
    }

}
```

}

P.S: how can i store the ouput in container and then bundle it and send to server ?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to put list of contacts in JSONArray,

**Step-1 :** Declare JSONArray finalJarray; for in future use to send JSONArray to server.

**Step-2 :** Generate JSONArray with contact name and multiple phone number. Unique key name to multiple phone numbers so that it can not override.

```
    public void readContacts() {
    try {
        finalJarray = new JSONArray();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("......Contact Details.....");
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        String phone = null;
        String name = null;

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                JSONObject contactObject = new JSONObject();

                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);
                    sb.append("\n Contact Name:" + name);

                    contactObject.put("contact_name", name);

                    Cursor pCur = cr
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                    null);
                    int tmpPhoneCount = 0;
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        phone = pCur
                                .getString(pCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        sb.append("\n Phone number:" + phone + ":"
                                + pCur.getCount());
                        System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                        contactObject.put("phone_number_"+tmpPhoneCount, phone);
                        tmpPhoneCount++;
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                   finalJarray.put(contactObject);
                }
                // outputText.setText(sb);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("finalJarray.toString() = "
                + finalJarray.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried on my device, let me know if any query.

Comment: thanks chitrang but contactObject has only names and no phone number

Comment: I tried on my device and, it has contact name as well multiple phone number too. Are you able to see log cat, then send it.

Comment: yeah just one line was above the if condition so i was getting that now its working fine thank you and there is empty set in array eg: [{},{},{"phone_number_0":"ffffff","contact_name":"aaaaaa"},{},{}] can u please tel how to remove this empty set

Comment: I have edited the answer, 1) avoid the counter 2) same as you did,

put this finalJarray.put(contactObject); inside if.


To avoid special case like 'ffffff' you need to mention if statement before adding to JSONArray.